# What is the secure way to include password in axios request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security

I am building a properties search app and to access the properties you need to pass a token and to get the token I've been given a username and password.

I am trying to request token which requires a username and password sent with the header.

I am using axios to handle this post request.

```
        let tokenURL =  process.env.REACT_APP_TOKEN;
        let username = process.env.REACT_APP_USERNAME;
        let password = process.env.REACT_APP_PASSWORD;

        const user = new URLSearchParams()
        user.append('username', username)
        user.append('password', password)
        return await  axios.post(tokenURL, user)
            .then(function (response) {
                localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)
                return response.data.token
            })

    }
```

But the problem is when I inspect the code I can see the username and the password exposed (obviously).
So what is the best way to handle this request?

Comment: Send via HTTPS using TLS1.2 or newer.

Comment: Since the HTTP request apparently requires clear text username and password, you can not hide this in your client-side code. The user will be able to see it, if he inspects your code or uses a network traffic analyzer. Your best bet would be to write a server-side middleware that adds the needed headers to your request or overthink your application design as a whole.

Comment: so if my url (in this example tokenURL) is a https url  I wont see the password exposed  when i inspect the code?

Comment: Inspecting code is one thing, sniffing on traffic is another.

Comment: @IvanRubinson as far as I can tell from OP's question, he's trying to hide the credentials from his end user. Using HTTPS would make no difference at all.

Comment: @Tobias Tengler  correct

Comment: That's not the way I understood it. Lets see...

Comment: This code, I take it, is executed client-side. How exactly are you going to hide these creds from the user if they already have that info (in order to execute the code)? Perhaps it shall be moved to the back-end.

Comment: does it even make sense to auth using username and password to the url since the response is gonna be publicly accessible?

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on what your overall goal is? Do you want to "auth" your users using a static username and password, I can't seem to grasp the concept of your application.

Comment: the application is a properties search app and to access the properties you need to pass a token and to get the token I've been given a username and password.

Comment: use https:// for your safety.

Comment: it is just dev mode i will switch to https on production

Comment: Use jwt to secure your connection then send payload with username dont include password  into token then verify  the token in server side and check username with payload

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by creating a server side file auth.php and now instead of calling the tokenURL in my react app and I am calling the auth.php url which returns the token.

Not sure if it is the best way to do it but at least no username and password are exposed this way

```
<?php
$url = 'http://example/login_check'; 


$data = array('username' => 'xxx', 'password' => 'xxx');

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { echo 'err'; }
echo json_decode($result)->token;
```